# Multiday or Multi-day

Tags: grammaticality, spelling-pronunciations, cultural-correctness, formatting

What is correct, Multi-day or Multiday?

I have checked the collins dictionary and it does not have an entry for Multi-day but does for Multiday ([link](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/multiday))

Despite that, almost every browser or device I use suggests that Multiday is wrong, instead, it encourages Multi-day.

Comment: Hello, paul. In situations like this, there is often a legitimate choice between spellings. Dictionaries' research can give different results where it's about 50 - 50. For instance, [OxfordDictionariesOnline](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/multi-day) gives only _multi-day_. Wiktionary is better, saying that both variants are acceptable. // New compounds and similar forms (eg as here with a meaty prefix)  often (but not always) evolve from the open form (not available here)   via the hyphenated form to the solid form. This usually (again not always) occurs faster in the US than in the UK.